# Timeout added in subscribe and promise

Tags: angular, typescript, ionic-framework

```
  this.btSerial.connect(macAddress).subscribe(      --- Add 5 secs max wait if no respnse then goes to next
             _=>{               

                this.btSerial.write(resultByte).then(  ---  Add 5 secs max wait if no respnse then goes  
                         
                  data=>{                                                            

                            this.alert.presentAlert("succe","Succ"); 
                            this.btSerial.disconnect(); 
                },err=>{
                          
                          this.alert.presentAlert("print",err);  
                        }
                  
          )},err=>{
        
            this.alert.presentAlert("Connect", err);  
           
        });
```

I have a ionic application which returns observable and promise .. In both i have to max 5 secs to waits and and then goes next iteration ..Can u please help me get the correct code

Comment: You should take a look at the `timeout` operator https://www.learnrxjs.io/learn-rxjs/operators/utility/timeout

Answer (score 1):

I recommand the timer operator provided by Rxjs :

```
     this.btSerial.connect(macAddress).subscribe(      --- Add 5 secs max wait if no const 
           
                 _=>{          
 waitForNextSubs = timer(5000);
waitForNextSubs.subscribe(x => {

                    this.btSerial.write(resultByte).then(  ---  Add 5 secs max wait if no respnse then goes  
                             
                      data=>{                                                            
    
                                this.alert.presentAlert("succe","Succ"); 
                                this.btSerial.disconnect(); 
                    },err=>{
                              
                              this.alert.presentAlert("print",err);  
                            }
                      
              )},err=>{
            
                this.alert.presentAlert("Connect", err);  

});     
    

               
            });
```

Comment: Thnks you very much...same I can applied for possible  add timeout to this.btSerial.write(resultByte).then()  function?